# how to take a a result from query to serch for it in another database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 databases 1st one for employees name and phone number and salary and the second database is for their accounts contain name and password and account type
my question
How can I make a query with php and mysql to search for employee name and base on his phone number will show me all other info

I tried to take $row["phone"];
to make a static value to search in the other database but no result to show

thank you

Comment: You have two tables and not two databases. In sql the join operation is used to combine data from two related tables based on a common data element. See the answers to the duplicate question how to join two tables.

Comment: No sir tow databases

Comment: What you described in your question are tables, not databases. The two tables may be in different databases, but that did not come across. If your tables indeed sit in different databases, then there are answers for you already here on SO.

Comment: Yes sir its 2dbs and evrey db contain a table this is ashort version of story

Comment: Are these databases on the same mysql server?

Comment: yse sir  both of theme in one mysql server